# How to stop my terminal from defaulting to old Python 2.7.10 to install Pyperclip?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install `Pyperclip` with `Pip` but I get a warning saying "Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020." and tells me to upgrade. Following that I get a bunch of errors with the install.

I have Python 2.7.10 and 3.7.3 installed on my system.

When I launch `pip install pyperclip` I get the error :

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting pyperclip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2d/0f/4eda562dffd085945d57c2d9a5da745cfb5228c02bc90f2c74bbac746243/pyperclip-1.7.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyperclip
  Running setup.py install for pyperclip ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/b5/yshbmh_d1352tytvt1r95hwr0000gn/T/pip-install-EKTm69/pyperclip/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/b5/yshbmh_d1352tytvt1r95hwr0000gn/T/pip-record-ntOrdw/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    creating build/lib/pyperclip
    copying src/pyperclip/__init__.py -> build/lib/pyperclip
    copying src/pyperclip/__main__.py -> build/lib/pyperclip
    running install_lib
    creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyperclip
    error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyperclip': Permission denied
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/b5/yshbmh_d1352tytvt1r95hwr0000gn/T/pip-install-EKTm69/pyperclip/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/b5/yshbmh_d1352tytvt1r95hwr0000gn/T/pip-record-ntOrdw/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/b5/yshbmh_d1352tytvt1r95hwr0000gn/T/pip-install-EKTm69/pyperclip/
```

I expect Pyperclip to install properly.

Comment: pip3 install pyperclip

Comment: I like to do: `pythonX.Y.Z -m pip install <package-name>`

Comment: You should decide if your question is about `pip` and two versions of Python, or if the question is about installation of `pyperclip`. These are two different questions and you're recommended to split the question in two.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
try to add a sudo before pip install otherwise you can create virtual env in witch you can install your requirement without having issues
```

[image]

Comment: Using `sudo` to install a package is a bad choice.

Comment: It worked but again it just defaulted into Python 2.7 site packages

Comment: so try to create a virtual env as other solution as i said later

Comment: @1000martians if you want pyperclip working with Python 3 try `pip3 install pyperclip` as you were pointed out. Never use `sudo` to install a Python package. It can mess your system Python.

Comment: try to create a virtualenv in witch install pyperclip that virtualenv will be isolated from your system packages @xilopaint is this solution convinced you

Answer (score 1):

You may need to call pip3 instead of pip